# Bulk insert into Eloquent Collection - Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, lumen

I have the following collection:

```
[{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_1","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_1"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_1"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_2","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_2"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_2"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_3","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_3"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_3"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_4","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_4"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_4"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_5","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_5"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_5"}}]
```

It was retrieved like this:

```
$collectionForInsertion = coretable::with($permittedTables)->get();
```

Coretable has 1-1 relationships with its associated tables. 
The models of these associated tables all basically look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class extensiontable_itc extends Model
{


    /**
   * The table associated with the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $table = 'extensiontable_itc';

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */

   protected $hidden = [
     'id_extensiontable_itc',
     'coretable_id',
     'created_at',
     'updated_at'
   ];


  protected $fillable = [
    'description_itc'
  ];



  /**
   * Many-To-Many relationship with User-Model.
   */
  public function coretable()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\coretable', 'coretable_id');
  }
}
```

Their migrations look like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateExtensiontableItc extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('extensiontable_itc', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_extensiontable_itc');
            $table->bigInteger('coretable_id')->unsigned()->unique()->nullable(false);
            $table->foreign('coretable_id', 'fk_extensiontable_itc_coretable')->references('id_coretable')->on('coretable');
            $table->string('description_itc')->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('extensiontable_itc');
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to know if its actually POSSIBLE, to do the following insert with some fancy, built-in eloquent ORM functionality or not:

```
$collectionForInsertion->push($inputArray);
$collectionForInsertion->save();
```

Currently, this doesnt work.The `save()` method doesnt exist for collection, at least thats what the error message suggests:

```
 (1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.
```

Furthermore, when using the following testinput:

```
{
"Internal_key" : "TESTKEY_6",
"description_itc" : "EXTENSION_ITC_6",
"description_sysops" : "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_6"
}
```

pushing to `$collectionForInsertion` like this:

```
$collectionForInsertion->push($inputArray);
```

results in the following:

```
[{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_1","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_1"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_1"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_2","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_2"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_2"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_3","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_3"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_3"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_4","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_4"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_4"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_5","extensiontable_itc":{"description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_5"},"extensiontable_sysops":{"description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_5"}},{"Internal_key":"TESTKEY_6","description_itc":"EXTENSION_ITC_6","description_sysops":"EXTENSION_SYSOPS_6"}]
```

The data is not appended in the nested fashion of the existing datarecords. Therefore, saving this collection to the model/DB probably wouldnt work anyway.

However, is there a way to accomplish this easily with laravel built-in functionality? Or do I need to write custom functions, looping over and accessing the models one by one while mapping the input accordingly to each model?

Comment: Related, but no feedback https://stackoverflow.com/q/60099351/984422

Comment: AFAIK know you have to write a custom function, loop over the dataset and map correctly to fit the model then you could do a regular bulk-insertion.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I gave you feedback on the related question (although the question is not the same, here its about inserts, not updates!). I don't think your suggested approach does fit my needs. In the meantime, I already found a solution to this former problem, I might post it there later.